# When using mingw g ++ in vscode, the characters on the console are broken

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When using mingw g ++ in vscode, the characters on the console are broken.
pls, help me :(

The encoding is utf8.

[vscode console.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oAnH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: I was not solved that way.